# quotes in bash when submitting r cmd batch commands

Tags: r, bash, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

[Problems with single quotes in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637643/problems-with-single-quotes-in-a-bash-script)

I have seen this post but my problem is more complicated and simply replacing single quotes with double quotes won't work. I need to run a R CMD BATCH command with single quotes and double quotes within the single quotes, something like this

```
echo 'R CMD BATCH --no-save '--args "xxx.txt"' xxx.r' | qsub -cwd &
```

What should I do?

Comment: I actually got a better solution as echo has a built-in option -e, through which escaped characters can be used. `echo -e '\x22\x27something\x27\x22'`

Answer (score 4):

Use a here-document, not a pipe, which eliminates the need for the outer level of quotes.

```
qsub -cwd <<'EOF' &
R CMD BATCH --no-save '--args "xxx.txt"' xxx.r
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

I use what I call a *5 quotes pattern* for that:

```
 'this '"'"' that'
```

=> `this ' that`

```
 "this "'"'" that"
```

=> `this " that`

Comment: It is somewhat ugly, but it always works. Using an AZERTY keyword, I try hard not to use the backslash which is a wrist breaker :)

Comment: thanks a lot man! Using your 5 quotes pattern I successfully bombed the cluster with 1000 jobs!

Comment: you are welcome :) although I find @chepner's answer more elegant.